# JFrame Paint having click-sensitive areas of the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouse, mouselistener

I was making a program and I wanted to know how to make certain areas of a JFrame activate something when clicked, although without a button, like you clicked in the upper-right quarter of a picture to activate something.

Comment: *upper-right quarter of a picture to activate something.*, do you have  picture and want to work this idea on it?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an List of Shape objects to represent the areas that you want to click on:

```
List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
```

Then you can add different shapes to the List:

```
areas.add( new Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 10) );
```

Then you add a MouseListener to the frame and in the mousePressed event you would do something like:

```
for (Shape shape: shapes)
{
    if (shape.contains(theMousePointFromTheMouseEvent)
        // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a JLabel object and set its icon to the image you want to display. Then add a mouse listener to the label object and implement all of its abstract classes especially the mouse clicked method to do what you want to do when clicked. Then when you click your JLabel you will see what you want.

The below code is an example to print "hello" when label is clicked:-

```
java.awt.event.MouseListener ml = new java.awt.event.MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("hello");
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        }; 


       jLabel1.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Comment: This also works. I ended up using the other one though. Thanks for the answer.